# Is there any way to supress the default size shown by WiX bootstraper setup in control panel

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, wix3.7

I am trying to install a WiX managed bootstrapper setup .I have written a custom logic to calculate the size occupied .Is there any way to supress the default size shown by WiX in control panel entry.

Comment: [Some old information here](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Setting-Estimated-Size-and-Version-td708659.html). The updated links to Raymond Chen's blog: [1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040709-00/?p=38493), [2](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180522-00/?p=98805).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ARPSIZE` property to set your preferred install size in case Windows is computing this value incorrectly.

```xml
<Property Id='ARPSIZE'>app size in kilobytes</Property>
```

> ARPSIZE seems to be superfluous at first sight. However, testing shows that Programs and Features reports a completely bogus value (over 4 GB) for very small packages. In this case, providing the package size manually can help overcome this annoying but harmless nuisance.
>
> https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/com-expression-syntax-miscellanea/add-or-remove-programs-entries/

More info about `ARPSIZE`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/arpsize

Comment: [Raymond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/author/oldnewthing) has a blog on why the size can be displayed so incorrectly: [How does Add/Remove Programs get the size and other information?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040709-00/?p=38493).